# Wordpress website designing

Tags: php, wordpress

I was told to design a website in wordpress which is almost the same as some web site which is in html. I was just given a jpeg image how it should look, and the content. Frankly speaking,   this is my first project  which  is website based.

So, taking all these things into consideration, can someone tell me a good way to make a  website in wordpress with the same structure as an existing website??

Comment: "*I don't have much knowledge of php, jQuery, or css and am running out of time.*"; honestly, take the time to learn these skills, but if you're running out of time, outsource.

Answer (score 2):

For converting HTML to WordPress, you should need a good knowledge on [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/)

You can also go for any of the WordPress frameworks listed [here](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/wordpress/free-frameworks/).

A WordPress theme is easy to understand if you know basic PHP. It has a set of files like

- header.php // header file
- footer.php // footer file
- index.php // the index file
- page.php // for your WP pages
- single.php // for your WP posts

and some other files
Go through the codex and it shouldn't take long to get the hang of it.

**But there is a impressive tool to convert HTML website to WordPress.** [**Theme Matcher**](http://themematcher.com/)

It'll automatically take your site, styles, images etc and create a wordpress theme for you. Check it out.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Hello libin ..can you suggest me some free wordpress themes with accordion tabs ..and the content in this accordion tabs should be from pages....as ny website needs accordion tabs  i can just edit the existing theme according to my need..please..

Comment: Just add any themes you like and then add [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu/).